# Pandas --Groupby Multiple Columns Return Last Value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Similar questions have been asked but cannot find my exact case (ideally without loop).  I have

```
df  
    A  B  C 
    1 30 101
    1 31 220
    1 32 310
    2 30 400
    2 31 555
    2 32 616
    3 30 777
    3 31 703
    3 32 844
```

I want to create 'D' where groupby 'A' and 'Last' of 'B' Returns value of 'C':

```
A  B  C  D
1 30 101 310
1 31 220 310
1 32 310 310
2 30 400 616
2 31 555 616
2 32 616 616
3 30 777 844
3 31 703 844
3 32 844 844
```

I tried

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C': ['last']})
```

but get

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Then

```
df['D'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg({'C': ['last']}).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

and get

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can make do with:

```
df['D'] = df.sort_values('B').groupby('A')['C'].transform('last')
```

Output:

```
   A   B    C    D
0  1  30  101  310
1  1  31  220  310
2  1  32  310  310
3  2  30  400  616
4  2  31  555  616
5  2  32  616  616
6  3  30  777  844
7  3  31  703  844
8  3  32  844  844
```